# how to count "natural" appearances of certain entities in a string python

Tags: python, string, split, count, substring

I have the following string:

```
sentence = 'aa bb aa, aabb aa.'
```

I'm looking for a way to count the following entities:

```
entity_1 = 'aa'
entity_2 = 'aa bb'
```

the end result should be this:
entity_1 count = 2 (only 'aa,' and 'aa.', the 'aa' in 'aa bb' should not count as 'aa bb' is its own entity)
entity_2 count = 1 (only 'aa bb')


I've tried using `sentence.split(" ").count(entity)` and `sentence.count(entity)`, but both result wrong counting.

Any ideas?

Comment: " the 'aa' in 'aa bb' should not count as 'aa bb' is its own entity" what code have you tried in order to include this constraint in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pattern with an alternation matching either  `aa bb` or `aa` surrounded with word boundaries `\b` to prevent the match being part of a longer word.

To reference the groups in code, you might name them like `entity_1` and `entity_2` instead of using the group numbers.

Loop the results using for example [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) and increment a counter if the found group is not None.

*Pattern*

```
\b(?:(?P<entity_1>aa bb)|(?P<entity_2>aa))\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group with alternatives

  - `(?P<entity_1>aa bb)` Named group *entity_1* match `aa bb`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?P<entity_2>aa)` Named group *entity_2* match `aa`
- `)`
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8TYZTE/1)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?:(?P<entity_2>aa bb)|(?P<entity_1>aa))\b"
test_str = "aa bb aa, aabb aa"
entity_1_count = 0
entity_2_count = 0

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    if match.group("entity_1") is not None:
        entity_1_count += 1

    if match.group("entity_2") is not None:
        entity_2_count += 1

print(entity_1_count)
print(entity_2_count)
```

*Output*

```
2
1
```